# Creating subviews using layout anchors programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, layout-anchor

I've created a `UIView` programmatically using `layout anchors`. Now I want to add a `UILabel` inside this view. Here is my code so far :

```
let centerView = UIView()
centerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
centerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
view.addSubview(centerView)
centerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constraint: 20).isActive = true
centerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constraint: -20).isActive = true

let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.text = "Testing" 
label.textColor = UIColor.black
centerView.addSubview(label)
label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

I thought this label would be displayed in reference to `centerView` but it is rather being displayed in reference to the `UIWindow`. This is the current view hierarchy :

```
UIWindow --> UIView (centerView) --> UILabel (label)
```

I need to add multiple labels inside `centerView` and as per my understanding, this chain will get longer whereas I want several labels to be all under `centerView`

```
         UIWindow

            |

     UIView (centerView)

     /      |      \
  Label 1  Label 2  Label 3
```

How can I achieve this type of hierarchy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, you just haven't provided enough constraints.  I tried your code in a Swift Playground and added a few additional constraints and it shows that the label is placed relative to the `centerView` as expected:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500))

let centerView = UIView()
centerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
centerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
view.addSubview(centerView)
centerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
centerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
centerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
centerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.text = "Testing"
label.textColor = UIColor.black
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
centerView.addSubview(label)
label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

---

Here is is running in a Playground:

[image: Showing the code running the a Playground]

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as well after some more testing. Thanks for the clear explanation :)